# Is it possible to create a "self-relationship" in one table?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I use MS Access 2007 and I want to create a relationship from a foreign key of a table to the primary key of itself.

I was wondering if this relationship can be created at the "Relationships" window of MS Access (where the DB schema is shown) and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this for future seekers:

Found the answer [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-06.html) and tested.

You just have to open the same table 2 times and create the relationship between them as usual.